# Show loading image after click button and page load

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

i got a problem in my project. I have 2 webpage, webpage xxx for the input and webpage yyy for the output. the processing time is taking 2 mins, so after i clicked the button on webpage xxx, it shows white, wait till the processing finish and show webpage yyy.

1. How can i replace the white blank with loading image and gone after webpage yyy is finished processing? i've done some research and the example is like this code

   ```
   function onReady(callback) {
   var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkReady, 60000);

   function checkReady() {
   if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
       window.clearInterval(intervalID);
       callback.call(this);
          }
      }
   }
   ```

the example is from this site http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/cbLsc81f/

2. Where to put the code and CSS to show the loading screen? on webpage xxx or webpage yyy?

I confused on how implement the js to my project. I need your help

Thank you in advance.

---

UPDATE.

this code is how i request the yyy page from xxx

```
    public void GenerateReport() 
    {

        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collections = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();

        collections.Add("ID", Session["ID"].ToString());

        string remoteUrl = "WebfrmReport.aspx";
        string html = "<html><head>";
        html += "</head><body onload='document.forms[0].submit()'>";
        html += string.Format("<form name='PostForm' method='POST' action='{0}' style='display:none;'>", remoteUrl);
        foreach (string key in collections.Keys)
        {
            html += string.Format("<input name='{0}' type='text' value='{1}'>", key, collections[key]);
        }
        html += "</form></body></html>";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
        Response.Charset = "ISO-8859-1";
        Response.Write(html);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: It depends on how page yyy is loaded and how request from xxx sent to server. but most of the time, it waits on page xxx until it get response from server, so put it on xxx page

Comment: can you tell more detail? the request from xxx is using `Response.Write(stringHTML)`  and on page yyy, the processing is on Page_Load. Call stored procedure and display it on ReportViewer. the process call SP taking a long time to finished

Comment: BTW, wait 2min is not good experience to users.
IMHO, request and watch later is better to users. It is just opinion.

Comment: It might not bad to put xxx page code here.

Comment: which part of page xxx code do you want? request the yyy page? i'll update the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="ui-widget-overlay">
    <div id="loadingDivId">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/loading.gif" />
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
function DisablePage() {
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('height', '100%');
}
function EnablePage() {
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('height', '0%');
}
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    DisablePage();
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    EnablePage();
    // Redirect to yyy
});
function GenerarteReport() {
    var url = urlHelper.CommonHelper("", "Home", "GenerateReport");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        ype: "GET",
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        async: true,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data.success)
                alert("success");
            else
                alert("not success")
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
public JsonResult GenerateReport()
{
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection collections = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();

    collections.Add("ID", Session["ID"].ToString());

    string remoteUrl = "WebfrmReport.aspx";
    string html = "<html><head>";
    html += "</head><body onload='document.forms[0].submit()'>";
    html += string.Format("<form name='PostForm' method='POST' action='{0}' style='display:none;'>", remoteUrl);
    foreach (string key in collections.Keys)
    {
        html += string.Format("<input name='{0}' type='text' value='{1}'>", key, collections[key]);
    }
    html += "</form></body></html>";
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    Response.Charset = "ISO-8859-1";
    Response.Write(html);
    Response.End();
    return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```